# share a datatable between asp.net page and user control

Tags: asp.net, session, user-controls, postback, viewstate

I've an ASP.Net page that loads user control dynamically , I want to share a datatable between them

I've used session state as following

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["DataTable"] = DT;
```

and Accessed it as following in the user control

```
gridVw.DataSource =(DataTable) HttpContext.Current.Session["DataTable"] ;
 gridVw.DataBind();
```

the data is loaded successfully but the problem is that in while accessing any event in server side or postback an error of invalid view state is raised (Only in IE)

Also Accessing the session from the page causes the same problem while postback

Here is the Error Page

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
>   FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters. ]
>   System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength) +10545429    System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char*
>   inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +71
>   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +41
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString,
>   Purpose purpose) +66
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Deserialize(String
>   serializedState, Purpose purpose) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter,
>   String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +40
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +127
>
> [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.

I think it's because session has long data or zero delimeter or whatever reasons that causes

> System.Convert.FromBase64

I've used another session variable (dummy number) and accessed it from user control to make sure that no problem at this user control and there was no problem

the question is i don't want to used Session to save my datatable ,, as I know its drawbacks but is there any other suggestion ?
**Note**: I'm loading the user control in the web page at static method (`WebMethod`) and this prevents me from doing any possible workaround

Comment: let's analyze it , does it worth calling database for a record rather that save the whole datatable once in a Session state and retrieve the corresponding record from it ?! ,, I can switch to get the record I want from the database to avoid using the session ?

Comment: how are you loading the UserControl dynamically in a WebMethod?  How does it get added to the page?  Note that I am asking because the ViewStateException should not be related to what you store in session and should come from what was posted to the server in the __VIEWSTATE field and unless that is modified it is based on what was saved to view state on the previous request to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to use session variables at all.  If you expose a public function (or property) of the user control to the web applications, you can assign the table to the controls.  Example:

```
Partial Class user_controls_myControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
   'create a public method your app can see:

   Public Sub bindData(ByVal dt As dataTable)
   End Sub

End Class
```

You can then access it from your main app like this:

```
dim mydataTable as dataTable
'fill the datatable
dim myControl as myControl1
myControl.bindData(mydataTable)
```

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer , I know that but the problem is I don't have the datatable at that moment so After retrieval I kept it in a session for further usage..in my post I've said that the problem is also accessing the session in the web page itself